# Segue between 2 view controllers (modal)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using the modal segue to navigate between 2 view controllers. Below is the 2 segue's I setup.

The purpose of the Segue is to navigate back and forth between the store url screen and the web view screen.

I don't want to use a navigation controller as this is NOT a common use case and I don't want the user to go back easily.

1. Is there a way to prevent a segue from happening? (I want to present a warning first)
2. Is this the proper use of segues?

[image: Segue setup]

Answer (score 1):

The `- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` gets called before the segue is being executed. Here you can do a check and return false if you don't want the segue to go through.

Comment: Great! This should be perfect. Do you think I am using segue's properly. Does it cause memory errors if I keep going back and forth?

Comment: Probably it does, why don't you have a navigation controller and just do push and pop?

Comment: I don't want it to be easy to go back. Is this possible with a navigation controller? Some sort of confirmation? I also want it to be at the bottom along with back and front buttons.

Comment: all you need to do is to hide the back button (the one on the top left corner) and for personalized back button have an action that just does a pop (or a check before doing it if that's what you need to do).

Comment: But then the navigation controller will take up vertical space. I just want navigation at the bottom.

Comment: You can hide the navigation bar (the one on the top) and have the toolbar (the one at the bottom) visible.